# How to determine the bit-width of the Number type in Vimscript?

Tags: vimscript

I want to figure out the bit-width of the built-in `Number` (integer actually) of Vimscript . In particular, I want to tell whether a `32-bit` or `64-bit` integer is in use. Currently I test whether the maximum constants of both widths can be represented:

```
let s:INT32_MAX = 2147483647 " 2^31-1
let s:INT64_MAX = 9223372036854775807 " 2^63-1

if s:INT64_MAX > 0
  let s:INT_WIDTH = 64
  let s:INT_MAX = s:INT64_MAX
else
  let s:INT_WIDTH = 32
  let s:INT_MAX = s:INT32_MAX
endif
let s:INT_MIN = -s:INT_MAX - 1
```

This approach has the annoying magic numbers in code. Although it can be replaced by `float2nr(pow(2, 31))`, which is exactly `s:INT_MAX` above, this requires `has('float')`. I wonder if there is any feature that can be tested like `has('num64')`. I searched through the `:h +feature-list` but found nothing more relevant than OS information like `+win32`. Any insight on this question is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly test for the 64-bit number support feature using:

```
has('num64')
```

The minimum and maximum numbers can be obtained using `0/0` and `1/0` respectively:

```
let VARNUM_MIN = 0/0
let VARNUM_MAX = 1/0
```

To get the bit-depth of these numbers, you can use `printf` with a binary format.

```
let bits = len(printf('%b', 1/0))         " returns 63
let bits_nan = len(printf('%b', 0/0))     " returns 64
```

You can just check if `bits` is greater than 32, or less than or equal to 32.

Comment: The `0/0` and `1/0` are nice shots. But the `printf('%b', 1/0)` did not work for me. I got `E767 too many arguments to printf()`. Maybe there is no `%b` specifier in my version of Vim?

Comment: Anyway, is there really _no_ `has()` way in Vim?

Comment: Use `%x` is ok. `4 * len(printf('%x', 1/0))`.

Comment: Yes there is `has('num64')`.

Comment: Anyway, is there really _64-bit_ Number in VimL? The help says vaguely that a number can be 64-bit or 32-bit.

Comment: I guess your vim is older than the %b flag (introduced in 7.4.2221).  Anyway, if `has('num64')` then vim's number is 64 bits signed, but your vim might be too old as this was introduced in 7.4.1976 (almost 2 years ago).

Comment: Got it, my Vim is too old.